# Deployment failure with the RPM built with latest jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

We recently upgraded to Jenkins 2.47 for our application. We used Jenkins 1.7 previously for building our applications. I observed a strange issue with the upgrade. The RPMs built with latest Jenkins are failing to deploy with the below error:

```
<Apr 10, 2017 5:01:43 PM GMT> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name : Bean with name  has been injected into other beans  in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example..
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name : Bean with name  has been injected into other beans  in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:568)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Apr 10, 2017 5:01:43 PM GMT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149231> <Unable to set the activation state to true for the application .
weblogic.application.ModuleException:
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1520)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name : Bean with name  has been injected into other beans  in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
```

I can build the same code on command line with maven (without running the job in Jenkins) and deploy the RPM without any deployment errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix the issue by downgrading jenkins to 2.34

Thanks.